# How can I make Ubuntu Dock show labels, not icons (like Windows does)?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, taskbar

On Ubuntu 19.04 how do I make Ubuntu Dock show the labels of running programs like Windows does in the taskbar? Also not to group them with dots but separate labels (again as Windows does).

[image: windows equivalent screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve something like that using some [GNOME Shell extension(s)](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481).

If you just want a separate panel at the bottom which shows the names of open windows, you may use one of the following:

1. [**Window List**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/)
   It displays a list of open windows at the bottom of the screen. You'll be able to minimise and restore windows by clicking on the window names.
   [image]
2. [**Window List Mod**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1033/window-list-mod/)
   It's a modification of the *Window List* extension. It displays a list of open windows at the top of the screen and offers a few more customisations.
   [image]

But an arguably better alternative is to use the feature-rich [**Dash to Panel**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) extension. It's

> An icon taskbar for the Gnome Shell. This extension moves the dash into the gnome main panel so that the application launchers and system tray are combined into a single panel, similar to that found in KDE Plasma and Windows 7+. A separate dock is no longer needed for easy access to running and favorited applications.

Dash to Panel provides an option to *ungroup applications*:
[image]
After enabling the option, you should get something like this:
[image]
(screenshot source: [this Ubuntu Buzz article](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2019/04/gnome-332-bottom-taskbar-traditional-layout.html))